# Bootstrap dropdown problem in Laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, popper.js

I started a new laravel project yesterday. Followed the guide from a guy in YouTube. Everything works until I installed laravel auth and realised none of the bootstrap dropdown works, even when i create new one from their website.

Firstly, I thought I messed something up in composer, because I wanted to get rid of the bootstrap and later I changed my mind and put it back. Then I created new Laravel project and started from scratch again. Even then my dropdowns are not working. I checked for similar problems in google, but none of them helped.

Comment: Steps to debug this would be: - Open your browser development console and check for any errors, for example the bootstrap library could not load because you miss a jquery script. Check which version of bootstrap you have in your project. Does everything else works except from the dropdown? Share some code so we can help maybe.

Comment: There are no errors in console.
As I see in package.json file, I run "bootstrap": "^4.0.0" and "popper.js": "^1.12". And what part of code would you like to see?

Comment: So following the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) all good on your side?

Comment: It turns out that some of those examples are not working aswell. For example, when I add menu headers example to my code, it is not showing up in the page, but i see the html code in dev console. Only buttons are working, but without dropdown funcition.

Comment: So that means that your bootstrap has not been loaded at all. Make sure that you include the bootstrap library in your view. If you are using webpack, check if you are mixing the external libraries into one, and include that one in your main blade file.

Comment: Ok, I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>` to my main blade tag and now it seems to work (except all the other examples without buttons), BUT now I have an error in my console. app.js:37421 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

Comment: Do you plan to use Vue? If not then remove the Vue example code from your app.js. Or if you do, then create an element with an `id="app"` in your blade file so the vue component can be instantiated.

Comment: @nakov, you could add your previous comment (with the library not loaded) as the answer. It just helped me. I split the vendor libraries from the app js and was scratching my head :P

Comment: @beerwin Thanks. I did it.

Answer (score 4):

By default, bootstrap.bundle.js is not included inside your Laravel app. To add this:

Open `'resources/js/bootstrap.js'` file and add the following code at the last line of this file.

```
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle');
```

Hit save and run `npm run dev` and it will work finally!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it is happening because bootstrap has not been loaded properly and I simply solved it by pasting this link in `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and paste this in the lower region of `<body>` tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your bootstrap has not been loaded at all. Make sure that you include the bootstrap library in your view. If you are using WebPack, check if you are mixing the external libraries into one, and include that one in your main blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you should change order of script links for that to work

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Your suggestion may be helpful, but reads more like a Comment, than a complete, self-contained Answer, as per SO guidelines. Please update with details on how to execute your suggestion. Links also are fine, with the caveat that relevant info must also be embedded into your post, so it is valid even if the info on that page changes or the link becomes unavailable. Link-only & incomplete answers discouraged, and might be subject to removal. Keep in mind that most Answers on SO require exact code necessary to solve the OP's issue. Or simply post as a Comment instead